# using cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n')

Tags: c++

So i was watching a tutorial recently about stringstreams and there was a code that does 'data validation'

```cpp
    std::cout << "\n--- Data validation ------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    
    int value{};
    std::string entry {};
    bool done = false;
    do {
        std::cout << "Please enter an integer: ";
        std::cin >> entry;
        std::istringstream validator {entry};
        if (validator >> value) 
            done = true;
        else 
            std::cout << "Sorry, that's not an integer" << std::endl;
            
         // discards the input buffer
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
    } while (!done);
    
    std::cout << "You entered the integer: " << value << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << std::endl;
```

and he said that the reason for that **std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n')** was to ignore everything in the stream up to the new line, i then copied the entire code and removed that line of code from it and ran it, inputting the same data he did in the test run(10(ok), frank(failed), .45(failed), 10 frank(ok)) and it worked the same way, no issues at all, so my question is why didnt it change anything and in what scenario would i likely need to use **std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limitsstd::streamsize::max(),'\n')**?

Comment: Is it just me or did the tutorial forget to clear the `cin` state bits on failure with `std::cin.clear()`?

Comment: @Casey `cin` shouldn't fail if any input is provided as it only reads in a string.

Comment: @IlCapitano Ah. I overlooked that part. The `istringstream` is recreated every iteration as well.

Answer (score 2):

`std::cin >> entry` reads only until the next whitespace character (see [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) for more details), so if you were to input e.g. `some thing` for the first prompt only `some` would be read.  After failing on `some` and reentering the loop `std::cin >> entry` would read in `thing` regardless of what your next input line is.  When running your program your console would look something like this (I added some comments for clarity):

```
Please enter an integer: some thing // "some" is read in
Sorry, that's not an integer
Please enter an integer: 42  // "thing" is read in even though you entered "42"
Sorry, that's not an integer // fails because "thing" is not an integer
```

When prompting the user you should read in everything in their input, otherwise some of their input might be left behind and read in incorrectly later.

One way of ignoring the rest of the input is via `std::cin.ignore(...)`. Another is getting the input using [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) which would read in the entire line.  Using `std::getline` would look something like this:

```
    std::cout << "\n--- Data validation ------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    
    int value{};
    std::string entry {};
    bool done = false;
    do {
        std::cout << "Please enter an integer: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, entry);
        std::istringstream validator {entry};
        if (validator >> value) 
            done = true;
        else 
            std::cout << "Sorry, that's not an integer" << std::endl;
            
         // no need to use cin.ignore
    } while (!done);
    
    std::cout << "You entered the integer: " << value << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << std::endl;
```

Comment: lets say i enter '12 three' into entry, when i pass that into validator and validator passes it into 'int value' what of the 'three'

Comment: when i replace the std::cin with getline, it asks for input two times, why?

Comment: @Padawan The 'three' would be left behind, and it would be read in the next time you ask for an input.

Comment: @Padawan _it asks for input two times, why?_ I just tried it, and I don't have that issue with either `std::getline` or `std::cin >> entry`.  Are you sure you removed `cin.ignore(...)` when using `std::getline`?

Comment: opps, that fixed it, but i'm curious, why did it ask for input twice when the cin.ignore isn't removed

Comment: @Padawan `std::getline` reads in the whole line including the `'\n'`, and `cin.ignore` will need another `'\n'` to stop ignoring the input.

Answer (score 1):

Using `ignore()` in this manner makes sense only if the integer is read *directly* from `cin`, but the code is reading a `string` from `cin` instead and then using an `istringstream` to parse the integer, thus the `ignore()` is wrong as it will ignore the *next* input on `cin`, not the *failed* input.

Not only that, but the code is wiping the `cin` buffer regardless of whether the input was successful or failed.

The code should look more like this instead:

```cpp
std::cout << "\n--- Data validation ------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    
int value;
do {
    std::cout << "Please enter an integer: ";
    if (std::cin >> value) {
        break;
    }
            
    std::cout << "Sorry, that's not an integer" << std::endl;

    // clear the error state
    std::cin.clear();

    // discard all input up to the next line break
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
while (true);
    
std::cout << "You entered the integer: " << value << std::endl;
    
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Or this:

```cpp
std::cout << "\n--- Data validation ------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    
int value;
std::string entry;
do {
    std::cout << "Please enter an integer: ";
    if (std::cin >> entry) {
        std::istringstream validator {entry};
        if (validator >> value) {
            break;
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cin.clear();
    }

    std::cout << "Sorry, that's not an integer" << std::endl;            

    // uncomment this to discard all input up to the next line break, if desired...
    /*
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    */
}
while (true);
    
std::cout << "You entered the integer: " << value << std::endl;
    
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Comment: `std::cin >> entry` reads only until the next whitespace character, so if you were to input e.g. `a b` it wouldn't ignore the `b` before the next prompt to input something.

Comment: @IlCapitano The original code ignores the `b` by the subsequent `ignore()` if `a` fails to convert to an `int`. My 1st example reproduces that same behavior. The 2nd example does not

Comment: The code in your answer wouldn't ignore `b` though, which could be a problem.

Comment: @IlCapitano the 1st example ignores `b`, just as the original code does

Comment: But the second doesn't. If you were to input `asdf asdf` for the first prompt and `42` for the second prompt it would fail even after the second prompt, because it didn't ignore the second `asdf` in the first one.